# Foreach through rows in DataTable: 'Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object' ' when getting cell value

Tags: c#, webforms

I am getting a the following error:  'Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object' '

```
private void InitAllTimeSlots()
{
    var table = new DataTable();
    string query = $"select TimeSlot from Time_Slot";
    _allTimeSlots = new List<string>();
    using (var connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(
          @"Data Source=********;Initial Catalog=*****;User ID=****;Password=******"))
    {
        using (var adapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
        {
            // adapter.SelectCommand = command
            // adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = query
            adapter.Fill(table);
            foreach (var obj in table.Rows)
                _allTimeSlots.Add(obj[0]);   //ERROR HERE
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `DataRow obj` instead of `var obj`. `DataRowCollection` unfortunately is not derived from `IEnumerable<DataRow>` so `var` cannot derive the correct type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your `foreach` to:

```
foreach (DataRow obj in table.Rows)
    _allTimeSlots.Add(obj[0].ToString());
```

Comment: When I tried this previously I had ommitted "To.String". This works perfectly, Thanks.